# Resizing an edit window

Tags: winapi

I have a simple edit window:

```
hwndEdit = CreateWindow(
   TEXT("EDIT"),
   TEXT("EDIT"),
   WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT,
   100,
   100,
   100,
   30,
   gHwnd,
   0,
   hInst,
   0);
```

I have noticed that when I paste there a text which is longer than an edit window width I get notification (EN_CHANGE) which contains only a portion of the text which fits a window width. I would like to resize an edit window (SetWindowPos) when a text is longer than the edit window width. I can create an edit window based on MSFTEDIT_CLASS and use EN_REQUESTRESIZE. Do you know any other solution or that is the only option ?

Comment: You know the [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/automatically-resize-rich-edit-controls) to your problem. Why are you proactively rejecting that solution?

Answer (score 0):

The text is truncated by your edit control on paste.

To allow more text in that control without changing the size (which is not practical for many reasons), simply add `ES_AUTOHSCROLL` style to your `CreateWindow` call.